# namespace autoload not working in mvc php

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload, psr-4

I was having name conflicts so decided to use namespaces but  I'm encountering an issue while attempting to implement a namespace using psr-4 autoload. I watched couple of videos to learn and tried this as I have never used it before. Please help to fix it

The specific error I'm facing is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "App\Controllers\BaseController" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\controllers\home.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\core\app.php(20): require_once() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\index.php(9): App\Core\App->__construct() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\controllers\home.php on line 8

baseController.php

```
namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Core\CSRFHelper;
use App\Models\Settings;
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Language;
class BaseController extends Controller {
```

home.php

```
namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use App\Models\User;
class Home extends BaseController {
```

this is my composer.json

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    }
}
```

init.php

```
<?php

require_once 'app/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'app/core/session.php';
require_once 'app/core/config.php';
require_once 'app/core/controller.php';
require_once 'app/core/functions.php';
require_once 'app/core/database.php';
require_once 'app/core/idatabase.php';
require_once 'app/core/app.php';
require_once 'app/core/CSRFHelper.php';

?>
```

index.php

```
require_once 'app/init.php';
use App\Core\App;
$app = new App();
```

this is structure

```
    ├── app
    │   ├── controllers
    │   │   ├── BaseController.php
    │   │   ├── textTranslator.php
    │   │   └── home.php
    │   ├── core
    │   │   └── config.php
    │   │   ├── Controllers.php   
    │   │   ├── database.php
    │   │   └── app.php
    │   ├── models
    │   │   └── languages.php
    │   ├── libs
    │   ├── views
    │   ├── vendor
    │   │   ├── composer 
    │   │   └── autoload.php
    │   ├── composer.json
    │   ├── .htaccess
    │   └── init.php   
    ├── assets
    │   ├── css
    │   ├── fonticons
    │   ├── js
    │   └── json
    ├── .htaccess
    └── index.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your point of view, you are using wrong namespaces.

App\Controllers instead App\controllers.

Or you are using wrong name for folders.

app/controllers instead app/Controllers

Be careful with upper and lower case letters.

Comment: Now i am getting this error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "App\Models\User" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\controllers\home.php:13 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: App\Controllers\Home->index('home') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\core\app.php(36): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\index.php(13): App\Core\App->__construct() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\controllers\home.php on line 13`

Comment: It looks like you have the same problem with all you class names/filenames/namespaces, once you correct the first problem, the second error will show itself.

You need to remember that all your class names/filenames/namespaces need to match in structure and name and respect lower/upper case, except for the App namespace, you already have an alias for it in your composer.json

Comment: I did, but encountered same error, match with it, this may cause because of route? Because, as said i used namespace later before i was using the route

Comment: You must provide your code again but how it is actually after your last updates or we cant know what is happening exactly. But I think you still have class names/filenames/namespaces to correct.

Comment: @RishabhRaj in `home.php` : You have `use App\Models\User;`. But I don't see that in your file structure. Is that correct? Also, to prevent casing issues I'd suggest making sure ALL files have the same Casing. Preferably "PascalCase" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) (second alinea)

Comment: @UlisesRendon i have upload the same structure please check https://github.com/rajrishabh1/project

Comment: Now I can see the problem
You have to follow the standard for naming your folders, files, classes and namespaces.That means your folders first letter must start in uppercase, and the name of the file that contains a class must start with uppercase and the class inside must match the name, for example:

app/Models/User.php => namespace App\Models; class User{}

Apply this rule to all your classes an their references in your code, and this will resolve your problem,For reference check the PHP Standards Recommendations page: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#3-namespace-and-class-names

Comment: @UlisesRendon but every class first character is already in uppercase, please tell me where did find it lower case, or can fix it in that, its really hectic,I am still unable to fix it

Comment: All of your dirnames are in lowercase:
controllers dir name must be Controllers, 
models dir name must be Models, 
core dir name must be Core,
libs dir name must be Libs,
and then the files:
app.php file name must be App (but in the index.php file you are referengin it)
baseController.php file name must be BaseController.php
home.php file name must be Home.php
and finally there are some references, i cant tell you all of them here, just search controllers/ in exact case match and repeat for the rest of the dir/files you change

Comment: @UlisesRendon I was getting issue because in my models file name was user.class.php and when i removed class then it worked , but can you guide why it was not working because of class, because when i was not using namespace it was working fine

Comment: @UlisesRendon Btw thanks remove class to make it work, and it is working

Comment: @UlisesRendon I have another question can you guide because, i cannot ask another question because they blocked me

Comment: @UlisesRendon , I using csrf token , so when the session_id is regenerating csrf token showing invalid.please guide ,https://github.com/rajrishabh61/project.git